# Angular Material dialog box not rendered correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, material-dialog

[image]

My angular material dialog box was working just fine before I updated the packages with latest version 10. I don't know what I'm missing in my dependencies or code.

It might be related with new Angular compiler Ivy or Angular material library.

Here is my package.json file -

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^10.0.1",
  "@angular/cdk": "^10.0.0",
  "@angular/common": "^10.0.1",
  "@angular/compiler": "^10.0.1",
  "@angular/core": "^10.0.1",
  "@angular/forms": "^10.0.1",
  "@angular/material": "^10.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.0.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.0.1",
  "@angular/router": "^10.0.1",
  "@popperjs/core": "^2.4.2",
  "animate.css": "^4.1.0",
  "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
  "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
  "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
  "jquery": "^3.5.1",
  "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
  "tslib": "^1.10.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.0",
  "@angular/cli": "^10.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.0.1",
  "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.7",
  "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
  "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
  "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
  "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
  "karma": "^5.1.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
  "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
  "protractor": "^7.0.0",
  "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
  "tslint": "~5.18.0",
  "typescript": "^3.9.5"
}
```

Here is my app.module.ts file showing entryComponents as it is needed for material dialog box. So you see I'm not making the most common mistake of not adding in entryComponents.

```
entryComponents: [
    VoucherDialogBoxComponent, 
    DateNoticeDialogBoxComponent, 
    ReportDialogBoxComponent, 
    EditTransactionDialogBoxComponent, 
    DeleteConfirmDialogBoxComponent,
    BeforeBaseYearWarningDialogBoxComponent
  ],
```

HTML is showing fine near the bottom left corner and not coming in the middle of the screen as a popup.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the result and the code?

Comment: added @Kokogino

Comment: And the code? Where is the popup in the screeshot?

Comment: In the bottom-left corner..It should popup like shown here https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example @Kokogino

Comment: What version did you have before? And can you share the code?